# Chrome disable dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a command line option where I could launch chrome with the developer tools disabled?  The scenario is this - I want to have an extension that will autofill info into forms, but if the form has a password field that the user *shouldn't* have, by opening up the dev tools and playing in the console it would be easy to discover, which is something I've been asked to prevent - is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going about this wrong. If there's a way for the user to mess with your form and thereby get into stuff they shouldn't, you need to fix the form and the code behind it. Also, Chrome already has built-in autofill that's very smart.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. There is no such flag in Chrome.

From a security point, passwords should never be filled in by anybody other then the user himself.

Answer (score 0):

The client should never-ever receive sensitive data that the user is not proven to be authorized to have.

And no, you cannot affect client-side applications. Chrome is not the only browser that has inspection tools.